# How to Replacing high-frequency image effectively on WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I wrote application that show images that i getting from some network layer. 
I get the images as byte array and i do Deserialize and convert the byte[] to bitmapimage and show it on my wpf application.

The image changes every 50 millisecond.

I thinking on a way to do it effectively - how i do with minimum GC call ...

I mean .. what do i do with the old bitmapimage when i need to create the new bitmapimage ?

Is there any re-use or something like that with the old bitmapImage and by this way to reduce the number of calls to GC ?

Comment: i think use GC.Collect() every 3-4 seconds

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик That is wrong. You shouldn't ever collect yourself on a generational GC unless you know what you are doing. You would push all your objects to Gen 3 and severely destroy performance.

Comment: @Дмитрий Чистик :: i want to reduce ... not to Increase GC

Comment: Performance here would be very much dependent on your pipeline. What is a `byte[]`? You'd probabily want to use a `D3DImage` and directly edit the image in the GPU buffer.

Comment: the byte[] is simple Bitmap without header ( contain just pixel ... without size, pixel size ) - and my using Array copy of this byte stream i can create simple Bitmap and save it on disk.

I can't and i don't want to use D3DImage - there is not reason to use it on WPF

Comment: may alternatively use **System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox** in **WindowsFormsHost**, repaint **System.Drawing.Bitmap** and **Refresh**  PictureBox?

Comment: How about (re-)using a single WriteableBitmap, and repeatedly call its [WritePixels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap.WritePixels(v=vs.110).aspx) method? No need for any WinForms stuff in your WPF application.

Comment: @ Дмитрий Чисти sorry but we talk about WPF not winform

Comment: @Clemens :: 10x - i will use the WriteableBitmap - hope that it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to avoid creating new byte array each frame. You can use Array.Copy (or C# pointers) to copy data from your network service to your image source.

However, if your network service consumes too much memory, because it creates new byte array for each frame, then you have a problem.

---

I have added camera live stream to my WPF application and noticed an interesting fact. I'm using EgmuCV to grab frames. It gives me captured frames as `System.Drawing.Bitmap`. I'm using converter to convert the frame to `BitmapImage`. The performance is quite well.

The interesting fact is, that when I call `bitmap.Save(filePath)` or `bitmap.Copy()`, it saves most current frame from the stream, not the frame when the bitmap was created. When I call save multiple times on the same instance of bitmap, I get different images. That means that the data under the bitmap are changing instead of creating new data all the time and that's what you should achieve. here is the code:

```
_grabber = new Capture();
....
//on frame requested:
Image<Brg, byte> currentFrame = _grabber.QueryFrame();
Bitmap bitmap = currentFrame.Bitmap; //System.Drawing

public class BitmapToImageSourceConverter: IValueConverter
{
    [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
    [SecurityCritical]
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) return null;

        var bitmap = (Bitmap) value;
        var hBitmap = bitmap.GetHbitmap();

        using (var handle = new SafeHBitmapHandle(hBitmap, true))
        {
             if (handle.IsInvalid) return null;

             return System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                 handle.DangerousGetHandle(),
                 IntPtr.Zero,
                 Int32Rect.Empty,
                 BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        }

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I did a little crutch, he can help you :)

WPF:

```
<Window x:Class="MyWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <WindowsFormsHost Name="f_WindowsFormsHost"/>
</Window>
```

cs:

```
protected System.Drawing.Bitmap m_Bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(yourWidth, yourHeight);
protected System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox m_PictureBox = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
protected Rectangle m_Rect;

public MyWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  m_PictureBox.Image = m_Bmp;
  m_Rect= new Rectangle(0, 0, m_Bmp.Width, m_Bmp.Height);
  f_WindowsFormsHost.Child = m_PictureBox;
}

private void timer_Tick()
{
  System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData = m_Bmp.LockBits(m_Rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, m_Bmp.PixelFormat);
  IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
  //or use System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(youData, 0, ptr, countBytes);
  Random r = new Random();
  unsafe {
    byte *data = (byte*)ptr;
    for (int i = 0; i < bmpData.Stride * m_Bmp.Height; ++i)
    {
      *data = (byte)r.Next(256);
      ++data;
    }
  }
  m_Bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
  m_PictureBox.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: this will crash because you did not added the pixel size on the Bitmap creation.

Comment: windows forms is really not needed here. If you need to use System.Drawing, than there is an easy way how to convert it to WPF BitmapSource without copying data in memory

Comment: @Yanshof i use bmpData.Stride (for width 100 and pixsize 4 stride = 400)